# preg_match preg-match

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Существуют дубликаты меток

- [preg-match](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/preg-match) (`_`) и [preg-match](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/preg-match)
- [preg-replace](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/preg-replace) (`_`) и [preg-replace](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/preg-replace)

Какой-то вариант надо оставить, какой-то предать забвению. Вот только какой?

P.S. если честно - все четыре метки можно предать забвению. Пользы от них никакой.

Хотел бы я видеть узкопрофильного специалиста по [preg-match](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/preg-match). Есть одна хорошая метка вместо этих четырех - [регулярные-выражения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f).

---

## Решено

Добавлены синонимы для всех четырех меток.
Ожидаем уничтожения меток - `preg_match`  `preg_replace` силами @Nicolas Chabanovsky

Comment: Хорошо бы удалить http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/match и http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/replace

Answer (score 9):

Удалить эти четыре метки, потому что они бесполезны и не несут узкопрофилированных вопросов.

Есть одна метка вместо всех четырех: [регулярные-выражения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f).

Также эти функции есть только в языке PHP, что в них такого особенного, что нужно завести отдельные метки для них?

Comment: А этично ли не-пэхапэшнику (мне) проголосовать за этот вариант?

Comment: Да, вполне. Мой голос был бы здесь, но за свои нельзя голосовать :)

Comment: Тогда моя совесть чиста!

Answer (score 3):

Если кто-то попытался добавить к вопросу [preg-match](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/preg-match) или [preg-replace](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/preg-replace), то вопрос определенно про регулярные выражения, так?

Тогда можно **[синонимизировать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/synonyms)** эти четыре метки к [регулярные-выражения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f).

Пускай пользователи узнают, как это на самом деле называется.

Answer (score 2):

По метке регулярные выражения есть [пара десятков участников с рейтингом > 5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/topusers).

Это позволяет достаточно легко создать синоним [стандартным механизмом голосования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/synonyms) - там нужно всего 4 голоса. Тех, кто уже высказался за удаление / синонимизацию, вполне хватило бы, чтобы уже создать синоним, без необходимости ждать реакции администрации. Заходите, голосуйте :)

Правда, синонимы для меток с `_` через этот механизим создать нельзя, но это глюк переезда с ХК, насколько я понял.

Comment: Хех. Нельзя предложить синоним preg_match. Придется руками метку истреблять.

Comment: @ReinRaus метку с подчеркиванием проще истребить силами Николаса. но в целом - уже хватает людей для создания синонимов просто голосованием.

Comment: Разумеется, я имел в виду этот механизм.

Comment: @PashaPash: новый движок больше не позволяет создавать метку с подчеркиванием, если есть с дефисом на том же месте. Более того, если вручную поставить метку с подчеркиванием, то добавлена будет все равно с дефисом. Так что большой проблемы с ней нет.

Comment: @NickVolynkin я знаю. но с двумя существующими метками надо что-то сделать :(

Answer (score 1):

Оставить только preg_match, потому что это написание функции в PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Оставить только preg-match, потому что это более подходит под стандарты именования меток на StackOverflow.